# slight texture on a flat ceiling

Tags: ceiling, paint, texture

were redoing our ceilings to get the popcorn off. Wife wants to mud the ceilings but NOT to sand due to dust getting everywhere.  Ive mudded as best as I can and its pretty flat using 12" blades.  I figure I can hide most of the imperfections with paint.  The stipple on a roller should do the trick, but I cant find any pictures anywhere showing the stipple of 1/2 or 3/4 rollers.  Which would give enough stipple to hide the imperfections without looking too clumpy?

Comment: Paint goes on flat, not stipple.  If you want stipple then most people apply drywall mud with a roller and then paint after.

Comment: I think you're just gonna have to experiment with various rollers and mud thicknesses until you get something that SWMBO likes.

Comment: Alternatively, rent a drywall sander with HEPA vacuum attached.

Comment: @crip659 I regularly stipple my paint with a 3/8" nap roller. I prefer it to dead smooth. Additional coats increases the depth of the texture.

Comment: Paint doesn't hide texture problems. Even if you buy "self-leveling" paint it only does so much. Prep is key.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a texture on the ceiling (or walls) is not done with paint.

You need to spray, stomp, sponge or roll on a texture using drywall compound, or spray cans.

There are various textures and methods.  The easiest is to spray a texture called orange peel, which can be very light or heavy.  You can roll some textures as well. [Roll on Texture](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Homax-2-gal-White-Sand-Roll-On-Texture-Decorative-Wall-Finish-2417/204335576?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-RM-RMP-GGL-D24-024_035_PATCH_REPAIR-MB-HOMAX-NA-SMART-NA-NA-MK684832200-NA-NBR-1748-CON-NA-FY23_AON&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-RM-RMP-GGL-D24-024_035_PATCH_REPAIR-MB-HOMAX-NA-SMART-NA-NA-MK684832200-NA-NBR-1748-CON-NA-FY23_AON-71700000090276436-58700007646538305-92700073880572738&gclid=CjwKCAjwlJimBhAsEiwA1hrp5taJKxbI-kJWF01jWH9XkWDKTuRnIWoO5tlLQSSM7rMfqrwAo4SE0BoCygEQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Depending on the size of the ceiling, you can use spray cans or rent a hopper sprayer. ( cans can get expensive) For a larger ceiling ( anything bigger than 100sq ft.) you should get a hopper sprayer. Practice with it and find a texture you like.

Here is a link to a video that gives a lot of info. [Spray orange peel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KztnOksM3Ak).

Once textured you can paint.

Answer (score 0):

I applied drywall mud using a trowel and varying the pattern. size of trowel can vary. smooth out with sponge if necessary. options are unlimited.  texmex look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding a comment on prep before the final painting. Popcorn ceilings often have ridges of drywall compound over the joints between drywall boards. If you have a bare bulb worklight that you can put up extremely close to ceiling level and shine in different directions while at a very low angle to the ceiling, it should show you if you have more places that need more floating before final painting.